# Beamer - remove extra space when itemize is used in columns environment

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize

The distance between the top of the slide and an `itemize` is greater if the `itemize` is inside the `columns` environment (see code below). How can I remove this extra space?

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\begin{columns}` with `\begin{columns}[T]`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
\column{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize} 
\item text
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```